# Hashing encoder in spark 1.6 for high cardinal categorical variables

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, feature-extraction

Folks I have a huge dataset which contains high cardinality categorical variable and therefore I would want to use some hashing encoders to transform the categorical variable. I am unable to find any hashing encoder in 1.6. I see that 2.1 and above do tend to possess some hashing techniques. Any ideas as to how I can do this in 1.6?

Comment: just use a python udf